# Step 10 of Canonical Distribution - Ubuntu OpenStack "Problem to install OpenStack Autopilot via Landscape"

Tags: maas, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I'm tring to complete all steps to have a Canonical Distribution installed on my virtual lab, the problem about the second network interface it's has been resolved adding a second vnet on a vnode (vnode0), but I stopped on 10 step. On Landscape UI all Checklist are green

[image]

then continued to configure the region

[image]

and launched the installation, and the vnode0 booted with juju

[image]

but the progress rest on 0% and not go head,

[image]

and after 10 minutes it failed

[image]

my question is after added the second interface to vnode0, that has not been configured (it's not an IP address)... maybe the problem is that?

During a second test I saw this error on a vnode boot

[image]

"route info failed"

[image]

"Can not apply stage config, no datasource found! Likely bad things to come!"

[image]

17/02: upgrade test
I've re-install everything from begin of the guide and open the details of that I saw that

[image]

```
juju ended with exit code 1 (out='', err='Launching instance
WARNING picked arbitrary tools &{1.20.14-trusty-amd64 https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/releases/juju-1.20.14-trusty-amd64.tgz ad7360aa5512b8d7cc1ad0ceb223bd9a1c8f5c6b0b131b5a3bd8fde623b85585 8130261}
 - /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-813df63a-b5ec-11e4-be67-5254006a0f5d/
Waiting for address
Attempting to connect to CanonicalDistributionSvrNode0.maas:22
Attempting to connect to CanonicalDistributionSvrNode0.maas:22
Attempting to connect to 1.1.1.11:22
ERROR bootstrap failed: waited for 30m0s without being able to connect: ssh: connect to host 1.1.1.11 port 22: No route to host
Stopping instance...
Bootstrap failed, destroying environment
ERROR waited for 30m0s without being able to connect: ssh: connect to host 1.1.1.11 port 22: No route to host
')
```

this the situation of MaaS Cluster and Landscape Hardware

[image]

[image]

if I active the DHCP service on Landascape don't see the network public, while on virt-manager this is the Vnet

[image]

why that, if I made the commissioning of all nodes, deployed Landscape and now I've a problem of this type?

Comment: anyone that can help e?

Comment: Did you check "/var/log/maas/*.log" and/or "/var/log/apache2/error.log". See for a similar error: https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1387262

Comment: first one is http://paste.ubuntu.com/10274456/ while the other is  http://paste.ubuntu.com/10274465/

Comment: 1st one has an error that you need to solve. Might be this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1376293

Comment: you saw the log dated yesterday if you see that ones today http://paste.ubuntu.com/10275295/ that error is not present. I've obtained that after to run the installation of OpenStack from Landscape

Comment: I suggest you try to use just juju with your MAAS and see if you can bootstrap. Don't involve Landscape just yet. It will be easier to debug.

Comment: I've upgraded the post with others 2 pictures about virt-manager and MaaS Cluster. Hoping that someone can give where is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved that added the second vnic on vnode where Landscape requests.

After to complete all its requests (green status) the installation of openstack-autopilot is going head without problem.

[image]

and Juju deployed all charms in right way.

[image]